# How can I know the idle time of asp.net application?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, session, forms-authentication

I have one application in asp.net with Jquery. I want to know idle time of application after loged in of particular user.

Y = 15 mins
If user X is loged in and then application is idle for Y mins then I need to show the counter them to after in last 2 mins your applcation will log off.

Y mins is configurable user wise. I want this from Jquery and I have used the forms authentication.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var idleWarning;

$("body,html")
.bind("touchstart touchmove scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup",
function(){     
    if(idleWarning){ cancelTimeOut(idleWarning); }
    idleWarning = setTimeOut(function(){ 
                  alert("12 minutes idle");
    }, 7200);
});
```